# Defining arithmetic operations on python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to define arithmetic operations on python classes.  What I would like to do something like:

```py
class a():
    @classmethod
    def __add__(cls, other):
        pass

a + a
```

But, of course I get:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'type'`

Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: Can you please give an example of your use case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a + a` would be interpreted as `type(a).__add__(a, a)`, which means you have to define the method at the metatype level. For example, a (not necessarily correct) implementation that creates a new class the inherits from the two operands:

```
class Addable(type):
    def __add__(cls, other):
        class child(cls, other, metaclass=Addable):
            pass
        return child

class A(metaclass=Addable):
    pass

class B(metaclass=Addable):
    pass
```

Then

```
>>> A + B
<class '__main__.Addable.__add__.<locals>.child'>
```